# Activity Dialog unwanted padding

Tags: android, dialog

I have made a `custom dialog` using an `Acitvity`.
All works correct but when showing it, I can see a small top and right padding, you will see it on image, the `top padding` is undetectable because all background is black.

[image]

You can see the error on top line and bottom button. All the `paddings` and `margins` have been set to 0dp, `layout` its set to `wrap content` and the inside elements with `match_parent`.

It's not a big mistake but I would like to fix it.
Thanks!

**EDIT**: In VM with android 2.2 it seems to run without `padding`, the image is VM 4.0 and i try with 2.3 device, both with that same problem.

Comment: You say `ayout its set to wrap content ..`. Can you try and make the `layout_width` to be set to `match_parent` ?

Comment: I tried it before post, it's the same result :S

Comment: Margins etc.. set on the textview?

Comment: I should say I have tried to delete all from layout except button and still the same result

Comment: Are you using a custom dialog theme|?

Comment: Yes:`
 <style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
  <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>     
 </style>`